# How to ignore a .ts/.js file in nuxt to not be generated in routes?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js

i'm new to nuxt.js and also trying to set a small architecture to my project.

i want to set my components like this:

```
pages/
  componentName/
     index.vue
     componentName.ts
     componentName.scss
```

the issue is when nuxt generate routes, i got:

```
/componentName 
/componentName/componentName
```

and the second route based on `.ts` file, i did change my `.ts` file to see if there's any changes, and yes the second `componentName` changes to match `.ts` file name.

and i don't know how to to ignore `.ts` files when nuxt generating routes.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `.nuxtignore' file to ignore files or extensions with Nuxt. To ignore all .ts files within componentName use this in your .nuxtignore file:

```
pages/componentName/*.ts
```

You can read more here: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-ignore

Comment: Thanks, it works. also i found this [pattern](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/configuration#the-ignoreprefix-property) in the configuration section. also for my case i set ```pages/**/*.ts``` ;)

Answer (score 1):

Put all routes in `ignore` property of your Nuxt config file. It is the best way to define all ignored routes in one place without renaming page-files or creating extra .ignore.

```
// nuxt.config.js
ignore: [
    'pages/admin/*.vue',
    'pages/settings/*.vue',
    'pages/*.ts,
    '**/*.spec.*'
]
```